# Why is an instantiated object viewed as not?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, grid

On the last line shown:

```
// Dynamically add Grid with 8 columns to the StackPanel
Grid grd = new Grid();
ColumnDefinition c0 = new ColumnDefinition(); 
c0.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star); 
. . .
grd.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c0);
. . .
// Add it to the StackPanel
spNufan.Children.Add(grd); // <- ka-pow!
```

...I get, "*System.NullReferenceException was unhandled  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*"

Yet "grd" is created in the line:

```
Grid grd = new Grid();
```

...and spNufan (a StackPanel) is in the corresponding xaml:

```
<StackPanel Name="spNufan"
            Orientation="Vertical">
</StackPanel>
```

Why the error?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line. Hover over each object (including the property) in turn. Which one is null? See about fixing that.

Comment: What happens if you add Debug.Assert(spNufan != null); and then Debug.Assert(spNufan.Children); after that, both before the line throwing the exception?

Comment: Where (when) do you call all this code? Looks like the GUI hasn't been created yet.

Comment: Not created yet? Hmm, maybe so...this code is in the constructor of the form that is getting those controls dynamically added. I was going to move the code out of the constructor, but hadn't gotten around to it yet.

Comment: I moved the code to the newly-created Loaded() event handler, and that problem has vanished. Apparently the constructo is a little too early to start creating things dynamically.

Comment: Before or after `InitializeComponent()` ?  Anyway, move it to Window_Loaded()

Comment: Or not...Load is not even getting reached. Should I put that code in another event, such as Activated() or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that your code is perfectly fine, but, in my opinion, you execute it **before** actually  `XAML` content is loaded and initialized, so I *suppose* that your

```
spnuFan is Null
```

Cause the code provided as is, seems perfectly valid to me. So consider it moving in different place of your app.

I would suggest to check this by adding a button and execute that Stack population code on `Click` event.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

`grd` is not null.

Either `spNufan` or `spNufan.Children` is. When you define the name in your XAML, you should be using `x:Name` rather than `Name`:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="spNufan" Orientation="Vertical"></StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that null reference exception is thrown inside the grid. 
I guess the grid requires row definitions to be instantiated either. (excuse me for being captain obvious if you are instantiating RowDefinitions in the skipped part of code)
If this is not the reason try checking the stack trace.